# How do I fill white background while resize image

Tags: php, gd, image-resizing, resize-image

Current background is black. How to change the color to be white?

```
    #assuming the mime type is correct
    switch ($imgtype) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $source = imagecreatefromgif($source_image);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $source = imagecreatefrompng($source_image);
            break;
        default:
            die('Invalid image type.');
    }

    #Figure out the dimensions of the image and the dimensions of the desired thumbnail
    $src_w = imagesx($source);
    $src_h = imagesy($source);


    #Do some math to figure out which way we'll need to crop the image
    #to get it proportional to the new size, then crop or adjust as needed

    $width  = $info[0];
    $height = $info[1];

    $x_ratio = $tn_w / $src_w;
    $y_ratio = $tn_h / $src_h;

    if (($x_ratio * $height) < $tn_w) {
        $new_h = ceil($x_ratio * $height);
        $new_w  = $tn_w;
    } else {
        $new_w  = ceil($y_ratio * $width);
        $new_h = $tn_h;
    }  
        $x_mid  = $new_w / 2;
        $y_mid  = $new_h / 2;   

    $newpic = imagecreatetruecolor(round($new_w), round($new_h));
    imagecopyresampled($newpic, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $src_w, $src_h);
    $final = imagecreatetruecolor($tn_w, $tn_h);
    imagecopyresampled($final, $newpic, 0, 0, ($x_mid - ($tn_w / 2)), ($y_mid - ($tn_h / 2)), $tn_w, $tn_h, $tn_w, $tn_h);


    #if we need to add a watermark
    if ($wmsource) {
        #find out what type of image the watermark is
        $info    = getimagesize($wmsource);
        $imgtype = image_type_to_mime_type($info[2]);

        #assuming the mime type is correct
        switch ($imgtype) {
            case 'image/jpeg':
                $watermark = imagecreatefromjpeg($wmsource);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                $watermark = imagecreatefromgif($wmsource);
                break;
            case 'image/png':
                $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($wmsource);
                break;
            default:
                die('Invalid watermark type.');
        }

        #if we're adding a watermark, figure out the size of the watermark
        #and then place the watermark image on the bottom right of the image
        $wm_w = imagesx($watermark);
        $wm_h = imagesy($watermark);
        imagecopy($final, $watermark, $tn_w - $wm_w, $tn_h - $wm_h, 0, 0, $tn_w, $tn_h);

    }
    if (imagejpeg($final, $destination, $quality)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Black & White

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
$final = imagecreatetruecolor($tn_w, $tn_h);
$backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($final, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($final, 0, 0, $backgroundColor);
//imagecopyresampled($final, $newpic, 0, 0, ($x_mid - ($tn_w / 2)), ($y_mid - ($tn_h / 2)), $tn_w, $tn_h, $tn_w, $tn_h);
imagecopy($final, $newpic, (($tn_w - $new_w)/ 2), (($tn_h - $new_h) / 2), 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h);
```

Here is your whole script (tested with portrait, landscape and square jpg):

```
<?php
function resize($source_image, $destination, $tn_w, $tn_h, $quality = 100, $wmsource = false)
{
    $info = getimagesize($source_image);
    $imgtype = image_type_to_mime_type($info[2]);

    #assuming the mime type is correct
    switch ($imgtype) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $source = imagecreatefromgif($source_image);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $source = imagecreatefrompng($source_image);
            break;
        default:
            die('Invalid image type.');
    }

    #Figure out the dimensions of the image and the dimensions of the desired thumbnail
    $src_w = imagesx($source);
    $src_h = imagesy($source);


    #Do some math to figure out which way we'll need to crop the image
    #to get it proportional to the new size, then crop or adjust as needed

    $x_ratio = $tn_w / $src_w;
    $y_ratio = $tn_h / $src_h;

    if (($src_w <= $tn_w) && ($src_h <= $tn_h)) {
        $new_w = $src_w;
        $new_h = $src_h;
    } elseif (($x_ratio * $src_h) < $tn_h) {
        $new_h = ceil($x_ratio * $src_h);
        $new_w = $tn_w;
    } else {
        $new_w = ceil($y_ratio * $src_w);
        $new_h = $tn_h;
    }

    $newpic = imagecreatetruecolor(round($new_w), round($new_h));
    imagecopyresampled($newpic, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $src_w, $src_h);
    $final = imagecreatetruecolor($tn_w, $tn_h);
    $backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($final, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefill($final, 0, 0, $backgroundColor);
    //imagecopyresampled($final, $newpic, 0, 0, ($x_mid - ($tn_w / 2)), ($y_mid - ($tn_h / 2)), $tn_w, $tn_h, $tn_w, $tn_h);
    imagecopy($final, $newpic, (($tn_w - $new_w)/ 2), (($tn_h - $new_h) / 2), 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h);

    #if we need to add a watermark
    if ($wmsource) {
        #find out what type of image the watermark is
        $info    = getimagesize($wmsource);
        $imgtype = image_type_to_mime_type($info[2]);

        #assuming the mime type is correct
        switch ($imgtype) {
            case 'image/jpeg':
                $watermark = imagecreatefromjpeg($wmsource);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                $watermark = imagecreatefromgif($wmsource);
                break;
            case 'image/png':
                $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($wmsource);
                break;
            default:
                die('Invalid watermark type.');
        }

        #if we're adding a watermark, figure out the size of the watermark
        #and then place the watermark image on the bottom right of the image
        $wm_w = imagesx($watermark);
        $wm_h = imagesy($watermark);
        imagecopy($final, $watermark, $tn_w - $wm_w, $tn_h - $wm_h, 0, 0, $tn_w, $tn_h);

    }
    if (imagejpeg($final, $destination, $quality)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

resize('teszt2.jpg', 'out.jpg', 100, 100);
?>
<img src="out.jpg">
```

Comment: I can't get it work. Image background being half white and half black.

Comment: @Blur There are some logic errors in your last imagecopyresampled(). I think, you can use imagecopy() here, because the image resources are in their final size at this point, so the edited answer is closer to the solution, but needs some work (the positioning seems to be wrong, but the background is proper now).

Comment: Actually I used the script from http://goo.gl/62sXo and change the math part to get constrain proportions for image. i'm stuck

Comment: I think you were very close to it.

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: Warning: imagejpeg(out.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me. Although it logically seems like it should fill the whole image with the $bgcolor, it only fills the parts that are "behind" the resampled image.

```
imagecopyresampled($resized_image, $original_image, $xoffset, $yoffset, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $orig_width, $orig_height);
$bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($resized_image, $red, $green, $blue);
imagefill($resized_image, 0, 0, $bgcolor);
```