# White background resize image

Tags: php, resize

I'm trying to modify this script: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/

I want to get a (when using the crop option) white background instead of black, as it is now. My scenario is this:

When I resize an image I get a black border at the bottom (1px) which I don't want. I want this to be white instead.

I have looked in this thread and tried to implement it on the script: [How do I fill white background while resize image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478223/how-do-i-fill-white-background-while-resize-image)

But it doesn't seems to work. Here is my code for the resize class:

```
public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
        {
            // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
            $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

            $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


            // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
            $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);

            // MY EDIT STARTS HERE
            $backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($this->imageResized, 255, 255, 255);
            imagefill($this->imageResized, 0, 0, $backgroundColor);
            // AND STOPS HERE

            imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


            // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
            if ($option == 'crop') {
                $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong and what should I change?

Comment: No CSS border set. It is just some image getting this black bottom border and others don't. This is - what I think - because they (with no bottom black border) have another width/height proportion then they who get the bottom border.

Answer (score 0):

Lil in hurry so can't write exact code but I was also trying to do something like you. Below is my code. I put comments it to make it easy for you. It must help you but please confirm.

In this code, I'm creating a trend image (Group of multiple images in single image), which have white background with multiple images

In short, I'd a png image as white background.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../dbfunction.php");

$tid=0;
if(isset($_REQUEST) && isset($_REQUEST['tid'])){
    $tid=$_REQUEST['tid'];
}else{
    echo "Trend id not defined";
}

//This return SQL result. Multiple rows with images name, x1, y1 as initial position and x2,y2 as width height
$data=getTrendImages($tid);

//This is path of background image. For me, background image is pure white png image (480x480)
$trendsbgurl= OS_PATH."image".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."trends_background.png";
//Get image in PHP
$trendsbg = @imagecreatefrompng($trendsbgurl);

//Loop to get images and put them on background
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
    $imgname=$data[$i]['image_name'];
    $imgleft=$data[$i]['position_x1'];
    $imgtop=$data[$i]['position_y1'];
    $imgwidth=$data[$i]['position_x2'];
    $imgheight=$data[$i]['position_y2'];

    //Path of source image
    $imgpath=OS_PATH."original".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$imgname;
    //Explode image name to get file extension. I'd to support png, gif and jpeg images
    $file=explode(".",$imgname);
    $ext=$file[1];

    //If source file exist
    if(file_exists($imgpath)){
        //Create source image in PHP
        $image=null;
        if($ext=='jpg' || $ext=='jpeg'){
            $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imgpath);
        }else if($ext=='png'){
            $image = @imagecreatefrompng($imgpath);
        }else if($ext=='gif'){
            $image = @imagecreatefromgif($imgpath);
        }else{
            exit;
        }
        $colorTransparent = @imagecolorat($image, 0, 0);
        //GEt source image size
        $imgsize=getimagesize($imgpath);
        //Copy source on background
        imagecopyresampled($trendsbg, $image, $imgleft, $imgtop, 0, 0, $imgwidth,         $imgheight, $imgsize[0], $imgsize[1]);
    }else{
    }
}
//I need to save image on disk. You can do whatever you need to do with $trendsbg
imagejpeg($trendsbg,OS_PATH."trendimages".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."t_".$tid.".jpg",100);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But Isn't this exactly what I'm doing between the comments: // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size AND // AND STOPS HERE? I refere to your edited version comment which ends before the "===============".