# Manipulating uploaded images

Tags: php, html, css

I've got 2 elements in my app that requires photo, first is club where photo always have to be square, then there is event image which most of he time is in 16:9 ratio.

1.
I'm thinking about displaying those on web page in original ratio but shrinked just enought to fit the page. How can I manage that?

**I wanted to try with  with** `imagescale ( $image , $new_width , $new_height )`php method, is there any better way?

2.
In case that event image would have 1:1 ratio(square), is there any way to convert a square to 16: 9 by adding white sides with code?

**I was thinking about** making container with white background and just place image inside of it.
Is there any piece of code that would allow me to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478223/how-do-i-fill-white-background-while-resize-image This may help

Comment: What have you tried and what blocks your progress? Asking subjective opinion may lead to down votes. CSS background-size (cover or contain) may worth a look (since you tagged CSS in OP).

Comment: Personally, I'd go with [Imagick::thumbnail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.thumbnailimage.php) that usually helps you resolve ratio and background fill issue. The third parameter helps you resolve best fit issues when you have a maximum ratio in mind. Just keep in mind that if the source image and the destination ratio arr inversley proportionate say a 16:1 source and a 1:16 destination youre going to take the maximum of either axis. So 160x10 pixel image is the same as a 10x160. Youd just have check if the desired axis is the one you prefer.